# cURL reading URLs from file - processes sleeping

Tags: bash, loops, curl, cookies, debian

maybe somebody has an idea how to solve my problem with some bash scripting.

Background: I have a file (urls.txt) with 30 URLs (one URL per line) which is used in a while loop to create 30 parallel threads with cURL to download/access those URLs simultaneously (cookie is required to access the URLS). The script runs in total just for around 10s and is started and terminated by a cronjob. In total quite a lot of parallel cURL processes are opened. Which leads to the problem of a lot of sleeping processes. ulimit -u is set to 47828 and ulimit -n is set to 1024. The script is running on a debian system. I monitored the processes/memory when the script is running with top -d1 and there is enough RAM left. When around 1000 processes are running it has almost an equal amount of sleeping processes.

Goal: In one of the 30 URLs there is at a specific time range a javascript embedded. The javascript reads out the cookie and the server processes the data. I need to be the very fast to be one of the first people (only the first 20 users count) to find the right URL where the script is embedded. Thus the parallel downloading of 30 URLs in a loop.

Questions:
1) Would it help to increase the ulimit -n to unlimited to avoid the sleeping processes and have them all executed? The script needs to be executed as fast as possible and sleeping processes don't help here.

2) Currently I'm downloading the URL outputs (with curl -O -J). Would it prevent the sleeping processes if I would not download the files? The curl processes would still run but no file would be written on the server to avoid 
open file limits? I don't even need the downloaded files because I just have to access the 30 URLs with the cookie data.

The current while loop looks like that.

```
while true: do

nohup cat urls.txt | xargs -P30 -n1 curl -b cookie.txt -O -J > /dev/null 2>&1 &

done
```

Comment: how many time do you need to call each url? because of `while true` and last `&` the process will fork infinitely

Comment: The while seems totally unnecessary. The middle line should do the job on its own.

Comment: I need to call each line as often as possible within the 10s the script is running as I don't know at which time exactly the javascript code that reads the cookie in the target URL is embedded.

Comment: I gave it a try with setting ulimit -n to 61535 but that doesn't change anything. I changed both soft and hard nofile limits in /etc/security/limits.conf for that and opened a new session to test it.